# Problems using javascript scriptcraft example code for canary minecraft mod

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I am trying to follow the examples given on the [scriptcraft example page](https://github.com/walterhiggins/ScriptCraft/blob/master/docs/YoungPersonsGuideToProgrammingMinecraft.md#the-young-persons-guide-to-programming-in-minecraft), especially the 'skyscraper' example. I found out that the script requires some modification to work, and currently my snippet looks like follows:

```
exports.mytest = function ( floors ) {
  var i ;
  if ( typeof floors == 'undefined' ) {
    floors = 10;
  }
  // bookmark the drone's position so it can return there later
  this.chkpt('myskyscraper'); 
  for ( i = 0; i < floors; i++ ) {
    echo( 'Floor ' + i);
    this
      .box(blocks.iron,20,1,20)
      .up()
      .box0(blocks.glass_pane,20,3,20)
      .up(3);
  }
  // return the drone to where it started
  this.move('myskyscraper'); 
};
```

But although the counter counts to 3 (or whatever number I specify), the 'skyscraper' has only one layer!

I make the call as follows:

```
/js mytest(10)
```

Has something changes for scriptcraft?

Answer (score 1):

A tad late, but maybe you are still searching for an answer...
Your problem is `this` always references to the starting point/drone, so with every iteration you are restarting from your current position. To avoid this you have to save the current drone-position (apparently it is not stateful/you get back a new object everytime you do something with it).
So I modified your snippet like:

```
exports.mytest = function ( floors ) {
  var i ;
  if ( typeof floors == 'undefined' ) {
    floors = 10;
  }
  var drone = this;
  // bookmark the drone's position so it can return there later
  drone.chkpt('myskyscraper');
  for ( i = 0; i < floors; i++ ) {
    echo( 'Floor ' + i);
    drone = drone
      .box(blocks.iron,20,1,20)
      .up()
      .box0(blocks.glass_pane,20,3,20)
      .up(3);
  }
  // return the drone to where it started
  drone.move('myskyscraper');
};
```

the important part is:

```
var drone = this;
```

and

```
drone = drone.box(...
```